# Qt: QML предназначен для Android?

Tags: qt, qml

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал изучать QML из-за его возможностей в плане интерфейса. Я хочу писать прикладные программы для Windows, но мне кто-то сказал, что QML предназначен для мобильных приложений. Вот в чем вопрос: действительно ли QML предназначен для Android, или на нем можно писать приложения на Windows?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/110544/

Comment: И на винде, и на андроиде можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, QML предназначен как для Android, так и для всех остальных платформ.

Что касается Android, вот общий раздел документации на эту тему:

[QML android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html)

Вот примеры:

[Примеры](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-android.html)

Comment: А писать приложения на Qt Quick Controls 2 для Windows крайне нежелательно? Или можно?

Comment: Qt кроссплатформенная библиотека, соответственно инструменты которые она предоставляет, в частности и QML  могут использоваться на всех платформах.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!